# Triggering a task in Airflow with the CLI run command

Tags: python, airflow

How do I trigger a specific task in an Airflow (v1.8.1) DAG using the `run` command from the CLI?

DAG

```
dag = DAG(
    'test_run',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=SCHEDULE_INTERVAL,
    catchup=False
)

one = BashOperator(
    task_id='one',
    bash_command='echo 1',
    dag=dag,
)

two = BashOperator(
    task_id='two',
    bash_command='echo 2',
    dag=dag,
)

one.set_downstream(two)
```

Command

```
airflow run -i -I -f test_run two 2018-08-21T18:59:51
```

I've tried the `-i`, `-I` and `-f` commands without any luck and without error. I've also tried `-A` for ignoring all dependencies, but that fails telling me there is no execution date in the command.

If I run the same command but specify task `one`, I can see that successfully show in the task instance list, but I cannot seem to run task `two` while completely ignoring task `one`.

Actual output when attempting to run `two`.

```
datauser@ubuntu-xenial:/home/vagrant$ AIRFLOW_HOME=~/code/dataprocessing/ /virtualenvs/dataprocessing/bin/airflow run -i -I -f test_run two 2018-08-21T18:59:51
/virtualenvs/dataprocessing/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
[2018-08-21 19:11:51,538] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2018-08-21 19:11:51,624] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2018-08-21 19:11:51,650] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
Sending to executor.
INFO:root:The key logs/test_run/two/2018-08-21T18:59:51 now contains 101162 bytes
```

And digging into the logs, I can see:

```
[2018-08-21 19:13:49,796] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-21 19:13:49,795] {models.py:1122} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: test_run.two 2018-08-21 18:59:51 [None]>, dependency 'Trigger Rule' FAILED: Task's trigger rule 'all_success' requires all upstream tasks to have succeeded, but found 1 non-success(es). upstream_tasks_state={'successes': 0, 'upstream_failed': 0, 'done': 0, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, upstream_task_ids=['one']
```

But should the `-I` flag not take care of this?

If run without the `-I` flag, but with the `-i -f` flags, I receive the same error.

```
[2018-08-22 16:47:19,582] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-22 16:47:19,581] {models.py:1122} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: test_run.two 2018-08-22 00:59:51 [None]>, dependency 'Trigger Rule' FAILED: Task's trigger rule 'all_success' requires all upstream tasks to have succeeded, but found 1 non-success(es). upstream_tasks_state={'upstream_failed': 0, 'successes': 0, 'done': 0, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, upstream_task_ids=['one']
```

Comment: The syntax looks right to me.  Can you post the output that you get when running the `$ airflow run ...` command on the second task?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added some more output.

Comment: Can you try removing the `-I` flag for `depends_on_past` and post the output of that if it's any different?

Comment: I ran it without `-I` and posted the output. It is the same.

Comment: Why the downvote on the question?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure.  At first glance, my impression was that this question was answered by existing docs but upon a closer look I think you may have uncovered a bug as the syntax of your command looks right to me.  Perhaps someone else had the same first impression — I just gave my upvote to balance it out.

Comment: It looks like this may be a bug with v1.8.1 which I'm on and corrected in v1.9.

Comment: Good catch - so if you upgrade Airflow to v1.9 or the recently released v1.10, do you still experience the issue?

Comment: I haven't tried 1.9 personally yet, but had a friend tell me that this does in fact work in >= 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Airflow version <= 1.8. This does work in Airflow version >= 1.9.