# Trigger a task in Airflow UI

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG with Task A, Task B, and Task C running one after another.
Is there a way that I can trigger to run just Task B and C from the UI?

From this question: [Triggering a task in Airflow with the CLI run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955417/triggering-a-task-in-airflow-with-the-cli-run-command), I know that we can trigger task from CLI.
But I dont know how to do so via the UI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on Task B and click CLEAR, this will start running from TASK B and TASK C

[image]